# Ruby YAML delimiter

Tags: ruby, yaml

Is there any way to change the delimiter that is used when Ruby creates a YAML file?

What is given right now:

```
--- 
- de
- abbrv_apr: APR
```

What is wanted:

```
\t de
\t abbrv_apr: APR
```

The `\t` is a tab, so basically I want all of the dashes to be gone from the created yaml files

I was able to fix my problem by creating a nested sequence http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#nested_sequences

Comment: Why would you want to do such thing?

Comment: ["YAML is a human friendly data serialization standard for all programming languages."](http://www.yaml.org/) If you mess with the delimiters it will no longer be "standard for all programming languages."

Comment: Yet Another YAYAYAML Ain't YAML.

Answer (score 2):

YAML is a format that does not allow for such customizations.

Of course, you can always do `obj.to_yaml.gsub(/^-/, "\t")` if you need to. (with `/^\t/, '-'` on read)